# Synchronize positions of two draggable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on an interactive application using a draggable time-line.

This time-line have two visual states (open and closed) and the users can drag it on the left and the right.

When a user toggles visual states, the application need to display the same time-line part.

HTML part :

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="on">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="image">
        <div class="fr">
        </div>
        <div class="en">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow left">
      </div>
      <div class="arrow right">
      </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="off">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="arrow left">
      </div>
      <div class="arrow right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to drag image sub-elements and not the whole timeline element.

jQuery part:

```
function _timelineOnClicked()
{
  return function()
  {
    $( '.timeline .on' ).fadeOut();
    $( '.timeline .off' ).fadeIn();

    // TODO : Synchronise positions...
  }
}

function _timelineOffClicked()
{
  return function()
  {
    $( '.timeline .off' ).fadeOut();
    $( '.timeline .on' ).fadeIn();

    // TODO : Synchronise positions...
  }
}    

function _timelineInitialize()
{    
  $( '.timeline .off .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ]
    } );

  $( '.timeline .on .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ]
  } );

  $( '.timeline .on .arrow' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).click( _timelineOnClicked() );
  } );

  $( '.timeline .off .arrow' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).click( _timelineOffClicked() );
  } );
}
```

Solution :

```
var _timelineLeft = null;

function _timelineOnClicked()
{
  return function()
  {
    $( '.timeline .on' ).fadeOut();
    $( '.timeline .off' ).fadeIn();

    $( '.timeline .image' ).css( 'left', _timelineLeft );
  }
}

function _timelineOffClicked()
{
  return function()
  {
    $( '.timeline .off' ).fadeOut();
    $( '.timeline .on' ).fadeIn();

    $( '.timeline .image' ).css( 'left', _timelineLeft );
  }
}    

function _timelineSynchronize()
{
  return function( event, ui )
  {
    _timelineLeft = ui.position.left;
  }
}

function _timelineInitialize()
{    
  $( '.timeline .off .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ]
      drag : _timelineSynchronize()
    } );

  $( '.timeline .on .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ],
      drag : _timelineSynchronize()
  } );

  _timelineLeft = $( '.timeline .image' ).css( 'left' );

  $( '.timeline .on .arrow' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).click( _timelineOnClicked() );
  } );

  $( '.timeline .off .arrow' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).click( _timelineOffClicked() );
  } );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're looking for something like:

```
function _timelineSynchronize (ev, ui)  {
    $('.timeline .image').css('left', ui.offset.left);
}
```

Which will set all `.timeline .image` elements to the position of the currently dragged element. It uses the `ui` object prepared by jQueryUI [as mentioned in the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag). Make sure that you cache the result of that selector (don't actually run it in `_timelineSynchronize`).

---

You'll also need to fix

```
  $( '.timeline .off .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ],
      drag: _timelineSynchronize( '.timeline .image .on' )
    } );

  $( '.timeline .on .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ],
      drag: _timelineSynchronize( '.timeline .image .off' )
  } );
```

to read:

```
  $( '.timeline .off .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ],
      drag: _timelineSynchronize // don't invoke the callback
    } );

  $( '.timeline .on .image' ).draggable( {
      axis : 'x',
      containment: [ 1280 - 1613, 0, 0, 0 ],
      drag: _timelineSynchronize // don't invoke the callback
  } );
```

You were calling the function, rather than passing a reference to it (as a callback), so it would have no effect when you dragged the elements.

Comment: I removed "drag: _timelineSynchronize( '.timeline .image .on' )" and "drag: _timelineSynchronize( '.timeline .image .off' )". It was a attempt to synchronize the two images and I forgot to clean the code before posting here.